# Name this PC DOS Combat Flight Simulator

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-game, simulator

I'm trying to remember the name of a PC DOS Combat Flight Simulator that I played around 1991/92.  I can give the following details:

- It was named after a US fighter plane that would have been in active service during the 1980's and 1990's.
- It ran fine on 286 hardware, so may have seen an original release in the late 1980's
- It had a dogfight mode where 2 players could compete via a serial cable linkup
- If you attempted to turn too quickly, you could experience a blackout/redout

Can anyone identify the game?

Comment: Falcon 3.0 would fit this description except it ran terribly on '286 CPUs.

Comment: Chuck Yeager's Air Combat also fits the description well, apart from point #1. I initially thought #1 said, "named after a US fighter plane *pilot*"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This sounds like [F29 Retaliator](https://www.mobygames.com/game/f29-retaliator): it has low hardware requirements, supports head-to-head play, and has blackout/redout. Only its name doesn’t fit: it follows the US nomenclature for fighter planes, but the F-29 never existed (except as the [X-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29) experimental plane).

The [Falcon series](https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/falcon-series) nearly matches, but not quite: the original [Falcon](https://www.mobygames.com/game/falcon), and its immediate successor [Falcon AT](https://www.mobygames.com/game/falcon-at), run reasonably on 286s (with one or two enemies) and support head-to-head play, but they don’t have blackout/redout; that appeared in [MiG-29](https://www.mobygames.com/game/mig-29-deadly-adversary-of-falcon-30) and was retro-fitted to [Falcon 3.0](https://www.mobygames.com/game/falcon-30), neither of which ran well on 286s at all.

Comment: Thanks, it was F29 Retaliator. I remember the Zulu Alert mission. I never realised at the time that it wasn't a real plane.

Comment: This game appeared on the Amiga also and was notable for having a very fast polygon engine for the time. No surprise its port ran well on low end PC's

Comment: Incidentally, the other aircraft you can fly in F29 Retaliator is listed as the "Lockheed F22", but it has canards and no horizontal tailplane, which means it's not the *real* F22, either. My guess is that it was based on early concept designs; the game was released in 1989 and the first F-22 prototypes didn't fly until 1991. The F29 depicted in the game is a pretty accurate reproduction of the experimental Grumman X-29, though.

Answer (score 3):

For dos there was F14 Tomcat from Activision, 
Air Warrior from Kesmai, 
F15 Strike Eagle but I don't know if that had 2 player functionality, 
Air Warrior had black out effects, I forget if redout was there also, but then it didn't have modern jets

Falcon3.0 sounds most likely but not on a 286
There was also F16 Combat Pilot from Spectrum Holobyte
And Mig-29 from Domark which I think had red and blackout effects

Comment: [MiG-29 Fulcrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiG-29_Fulcrum_(1990_video_game)) was the game I was trying to remember when I found this question.  So there is the full name of that for anyone, and thanks for the hint!